# Mouse Control using wii nunchuck

Tags: c#, mouse

Currently i'm able to read info from the wii nunchuck in a C# application.

For learning pourposes, I want to program an application that controls the mouse using the wii nunchuck.

What is the simplest way to take control of the mouse programatically? do I need to use the windows API?

I need to move the pointer and simulate clicks.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 Just because it's a nice idea, trying stuff a little bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [WiiCursor](http://www.codeplex.com/WiiCursor) on CodePlex it looks like it does what you want, or you could lift the cursor code from there and integrate with your own code.

BTW Have you seen Johnny Chung Lee's uber cool [touch whiteboard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5s5EvhHy7eQ&feature=related)

Comment: Johnny Chung Lee is a genious... :D